# Best practices regarding using instance_eval to stub while writing specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a lot of code which looks like this, and I'm having trouble writing tests for it:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def my_endpoint
    id = current_user.site_id
    do_something_with id
  end
end
```

`current_user` is supplied by the zendesk_api gem, which we use for authentication. specifically, `current_user` is a method on `client.rb`: `zendesk_api-1.14.4/lib/zendesk_api/client.rb#current_user`.

I discovered I can stub `MyController#current_user` by using instance_eval in my spec:

```
describe "#my_endpoint" do
it "should etc" do
  controller = MyController.new
  controller.instance_eval do
    def current_user
      return OpenStruct.new(:site_id => 1)
    end
  end

  response = controller.my_endpoint
end
```

I think this spec code looks good. It's readable and flexible. However, I was unable to find best practices regarding this usage of `instance_eval`.

Is this a conventional usage of `instance_eval`? Is there a convention I should use instead? Are there any best practices I should follow regarding `instance_eval` usage in spec, or otherwise stubbing 3rd party calls in specs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are testing a controller here and are using rspec, you should [define the tests as one such](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs):

```rb
describe MyController, type: :controller do
  ...(tests here)
end
```

Within such a controller test you have access to the controller instance via the `controller` method and can stub the call to `current_user` using [rspec's mocking capabilities](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs)

```rb
describe MyController, type: :controller do
  before do
    allow(controller)
      .to_receive(:current_user)
      .and_return(OpenStruct.new(:site_id => 1))
  end

  it 'is testing something' do
    ...
  end
end
```